# ios: Center view in its superview

Tags: ios, swift, view, position, autolayout

I'm trying to center `my subview` with a `button` in its`superview`. So I want the center of the `subview` be the center of the `superview`. I'm trying that with following code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    var menuView = UIView()
    var newPlayButton = UIButton()
    //var newPlayImage = UIImage(named: "new_game_button_5cs")
    var newPlayImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "new_game_button_5cs"))
    newPlayButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, newPlayImageView.frame.width, newPlayImageView.frame.height)
    newPlayButton.setImage(newPlayImage, forState: .Normal)
    newPlayButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    menuView.center = self.view.center
    menuView.center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2, self.view.bounds.size.height / 2)
    menuView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()*/
    menuView.addSubview(newPlayButton)
}
```

Unfortunately it doesent seem to work as this is the result:

[image]

Comment: Autolayout and constraints can help you

Answer (score 3):

```
    UIView *subview = your View To Be Centered In Its SuperView;

    UIView *superView = subview.superview;

    subview.center = [superView convertPoint:superView.center
                                    fromView:superView.superview];
```

If view is nil(on fromView:), this method instead converts from window base coordinates. Otherwise, both view and the receiver must belong to the same UIWindow object.

**NOTE: If you use the auto layout stuff, then you have to change the constraints . not the frame or center.**

Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing your view width from your superview width, e.g.:

```
var width: CGFloat = (self.view.bounds.size.width / 2)

// (here goes your view width that you want centralize)

menuView.center = CGPointMake(width, self.view.bounds.size.height / 2)
```

**My working code**

vRate = superview
rcRating = view ( that I want to centralize in vRate )

```
self.rcRating = AMRatingControl(location: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), andMaxRating: 5)
self.vRate.addSubview(self.rcRating)

var width: CGFloat = (self.vRate.bounds.size.width / 2) - self.rcRating.bounds.size.width
self.rcRating.center = CGPointMake(width, self.vRate.bounds.size.height / 2)
```